# Custom user interface to act as a replacement for explorer.exe in Windows

Tags: windows, file-management, user-interface

When you go to `gpedit.msc` > `User configuration` > `administrative templates` > `system` > `custom user interface` there's an option for setting a different user interface from `explorer.exe` .
 I want to do that. I want a different look(I didn't have this desire till I saw that option). 
I have tried a couple of file managers/browsers e.g Cubic,Explorer++ and Orbitz and I like Cubic explorer the best, but they only help in viewing my files and folders. 
Programs don't run on 'top' of them. I set Cubic in gpedit and restarted only to find that the startup programs did not run at startup, only Cubic explorer was running on a black screen like in safe mode with command prompt and networking. 
I had to run cmd from cubic explorer in order to run cmd.exe . 
**Is there a program that can fully serve as a replacement or alternative to explorer.exe?** 
If not, at least show me how to set Cubic explorer to be the default file manager. Even though there is an option for registering it as a file manager, it doesn't autoplay when I plug in a phone or flash drive.

Comment: Upvoted and bookmarked this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not replacing **just** the file browser in windows when you change that option, **you are replacing the entire [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29)**.

Setting the shell as a alternative file browser will not work (as you discovered) as the shell is responsible for a lot more than just browsing your files.

Wikipedia provides a [list of alternative shells for windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows), I have never tried any of them so I cannot say if they are good or bad.

```
+-------------------------+----------------+--------------------+
|         Shell           |     Type       |         OS         |
+-------------------------+----------------+--------------------+
| Cairo Shell             | Closed source  | XP, Vista, 7       |
| Calmira                 | Open source    | 3.1                |
| Classic Shell           | Open source    | Vista, 7, 8, 10    |
| Emerge Desktop          | Open source    | 2000, XP, Vista, 7 |
| GreenGnome*             | Open source    | XP                 |
| LDE(X)                  | Open source    | 2000, XP           |
| LiteStep                | Open source    | 95+                |
| BB4Win                  | Open source    | 95+                |
| bbLean                  | Open source    | 95+                |
| SharpEnviro*            | Open source    | XP, Vista, 7       |
| KDE Windows             | Open source    | XP, Vista, 7       |
| BumpTop*                | Proprietary    | XP, Vista, 7       |
| Packard Bell Navigator  | Proprietary    | 3.1, 95            |
| Talisman Desktop        | Proprietary    | 95+                |
| Aston Shell             | Proprietary    | 95+                |
| TabWorks*               | Proprietary    | 3.x, 95            |
+-------------------------+----------------+--------------------+
(*Discontinued)
```

Comment: I didn't know there were other shells. I'll try them out. How about making x file manager the default?

Comment: I have tried Cairo, Classic shell and Emerge and honestly, they don't look better than explorer. I feel slower when using them. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I am running a version of TabWorks on Windows 10 that was made for Windows 95. My first Win3.1 PC had TabWorks and I found version 2.5 (1996).

Comment: @Segfault Really, I feel like the Windows 10 Start Menu is much slower than Classic Shell start menu.